# How can I define input and output tensors in PyTorch?

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, pytorch

I'm new to neural networks and PyTorch in particular, so please excuse my question if it turns out to be a simple one. I am creating a simple neural network that can predict the presence of lung cancer based on a given dataset.

I've reached the point where I have to create my input and output tensors with which to train my network. Unfortunately, I've run into an error while creating the tensors, and I'm not sure how to resolve it.

[image: This was my attempt.]

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using vectors/matrices of numbers to create tensors. Right now you seem to be passing strings describing the data rather than the data itself.